# Is it possible to sum values in column C into column D, ONLY when all adjacent values in columns A and B are the same?

Tags: excel, sum, pivot-table

I want to generate one autosum value for column C, for every instance where there is an equal number of rows in both column A and B, where the value in A does not change and the value of B does not change within that row.

I.e. column A contains cost centre numbers, and column B contains supplier numbers. In column C are the values for each payment to a supplier. I want a sum of all the payments to one supplier and one cost centre, to appear in column D.

Comment: Hi pnuts, thanks for the advice. A pivotTable ended up being an excellent option.

Answer (score 1):

One possible layout achievable with a PivotTable (`Sum of Payments` being in ColumnD):

[image: SO20896543 example]